# Fail2ban reading logs from the syslog/process/stdout of other task

Tags: logging, docker, fail2ban, logrotate

I have a list of docker containers running on a server. One of the containers is (will be) fail2ban running on `privileged` mode. My problem right now is with passing and sharing the same volume (log file) through these containers in order for it to be written by services and read by fail2ban.

I was wondering if there's a way with fail2ban to read from a stream of data like `docker logs -f apache`. This would take the pain away from managing that logfile, passing it through containers, dealing with read/write locks and also figuring out how to rotate it.

Comment: Hey there. I know this is pretty old but how did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Configure the docker to write logs to syslog/ journald https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/

```
docker run --log-driver=syslog ...
```